# How to optimize the julia differential equation solution

Tags: arrays, julia, atom-editor, differentialequations.jl

I am running the following Julia code to solve a set of differential equations, but it takes too much time, and sometimes my machine gets crushed. Is there any solution to reduce the running time and memory usage? I am not too familiar with Julia. So a help would be very much appreciated.

```
using DelimitedFiles
using LinearAlgebra
using Random
using PyPlot
using BenchmarkTools
using SparseArrays
using Distributions
using DifferentialEquations



N=10000;
Random.seed!(123)
d=Cauchy()
omega=rand(d,N);

function kuramoto(du, u, pp, t)

    u1 = @view u[1:N] #### θ
    du1 = @view du[1:N]  #### dθ
    u2 = @view u[N+1:2*N]  ####### λ
    du2 = @view du[N+1:2*N]  ####### dλ

    a=1
    b=3
    α=0.005
    β=0.002
    λ0=pp

    z1 = Array{Complex{Float64},1}(undef, N)
    z1=mean(cis,u1)
    z1c=conj(z1)

    z2 = Array{Complex{Float64},1}(undef, N)
    z2=mean(cis,2*u1)




    ####### equ of motion
    @. du1  = omega + u2 *(a*( imag(z1  * exp((-1im) * (u1)) )) + b*(imag(z2 * z1c * exp((-1im) * (u1)) )))
    @. du2 = α *(λ0-u2)- β * (abs(z1))

    return nothing
end;


# setting up time steps and integration intervals

dt = 0.01 # time step
dts = 0.1 # save time
ti = 0.0
tt = 1000.0
tf = 20000.0
nt = Int(div(tt,dts))
nf = Int(div(tf,dts))

tspan = (ti, tf); # time interval
t=range(0,stop=tf-tt,length=nf-nt+1);

pp=2.05
Random.seed!(123)
u0=[rand(N)*2*pi;pp*ones(N)];
du = similar(u0);


prob = ODEProblem(kuramoto, u0, tspan, pp)
sol = solve(prob, RK4(), reltol=1e-4, saveat=dts,progress=true);



function global_order(_u)
    _R_global = zeros(nf-nt+1)

    for n in nt:nf
        _re = mean(j -> cos(_u[j,n]), 1:N)
        _im = mean(j -> sin(_u[j,n]), 1:N)
        _R_global[n-nt+1] = sqrt(_re^2 + _im^2)
    end

    return (_R_global)
end;


r1= global_order(sol[1:N,:]);


ppp=[t r1];
writedlm("k2=3_cauchy_time_order_hoi_α=0.005_β=0.002_λ0=$pp.txt",ppp)


λ_avg=mean(sol[N+1:2*N,:],dims=1)[nt:nf];
qqq=[λ_avg r1];
writedlm("k2=3_cauchy_λ_avg,R_α=0.005_β=0.002_λ0=$pp.txt",qqq)


clf()
plot(t,r1,c="blue")
ylim([0,1])
xlabel("time")
ylabel("order parameter R")
title("λ=$pp")
gcf()
```

I have to solve it with the RK4 method only.

Comment: @Shayan Cauchy() means standard Cauchy distribution. I am randomly taking 10000 elements from the standard Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Which part of your code is slow? I see a plotting procedure in the last phase of your script, which can consume much time at the first run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just calculate it out. You're saving `((20000.0 - 1000.0) / 0.1) = 190000.0` steps of a `2 * 10000 = 20000` length array. This means the solution is `((20000.0 - 1000.0) / 0.1) * (2 * 10000) = 3.8e9` 64-bit numbers, or [30.4 GB](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3.8e9+*+64+bits). Then you slice half of it here in `global_order(sol[1:N,:]);`. so that slice will make an extra 15 GB. If you don't have 45 GB of RAM, your computer will crash at this point. So yeah, not really surprising: don't tell it to generate 45 GB of vectors if it cannot be stored. That's also going to be horrible for performance.

The solution of course is just to not save so much. Use [the saving callback](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqCallbacks/stable/output_saving/#Saving-Example) so that you just save the time series for `_R_global` array. Saving a size 1 object every time step instead of 20000 is going to be a huge difference.

For your code, this would look like:

```
saved_values = SavedValues(Float64, Float64)
function saver(u,t,integrator)
    _re = mean(cos.(u))
    _im = mean(sin.(u))
    out = sqrt(_re^2 + _im^2)
end
cb = SavingCallback(saver, saved_values)
```

and then change the solve call to:

```
sol = solve(prob, RK4(), reltol=1e-4, saveat=dts,progress=true,callback = cb);
```

then after solving, `saved_values.u` will be the array of values you want.

## P.S.

Also, the number of steps `20000.0 - 1000.0 = 190000` looks odd: almost surely that's a typo meant to be 1000 to 2000 not 20000?

Comment: can you please help me use this call back in my code?  I have followed the link but am unable to understand it properly.

Comment: I added an example of how to use it.

Comment: if I am not wrong, is not the callback function doing the exponential mean of all the 2000 variables at each time, ??  but as in my code, I want the exponential mean of only the first 1000 variables and for the other 1000 variables only mean is needed.

Comment: yes, I missed that, but just slice it etc. from here you can take it.